# What is following limit?

Tags: limits, mathematica

$\mathsf{Mathematica}$ evaluates $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\binom{N^{\frac{3}{2}}-N^{\frac{1}{2}}}{N^{1-8\epsilon}}}{\binom{N^{\frac{3}{2}}}{N^{1-8\epsilon}}}$$ to $e^{-1}$.

Is it much different from
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\binom{N^{\frac{3}{2}}-N^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{N}{(\log N)^{8}}}}{\binom{N^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{N}{(\log N)^{8}}}}$$ 
on which $\mathsf{Mathematica}$ craps out?

Comment: So you are using a generalized version of the $\binom{a}{b}$?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Whatever is implemented in $\mathsf{mathematica}$.

Comment: So you are asking a question without knowing how the expressions you use are defined?

Comment: For any *fixed* $N$, the inner limit as $\epsilon\to0$ gives the same expression, which simply has an $N$ for the bottom part of each binomial coefficient.  So it looks to me like you're just asking for $$\lim_{N\to\infty}{{N^{3/2}-N^{1/2}\choose N}\over{N^{3/2}\choose N}}$$

Comment: Oh, wait, bad eyesight on my part.  There is no $\epsilon$ in the second expression.  I assumed there was one, and misread the $(\log N)^8$ as $(\log N)^\epsilon$.